# loading a satellite image in web app

Tags: java, html

I have to load a `.tif` format image in a website. I am using HTML5 in Eclipse as a test case. because of the image size is very large approximately 500 MB. The image is not displayed on the web page. I only get the "alt" text. any solution?

Comment: Yes, don't try to show ridiculously large images like that. No user would want to see his computer choke when entering a website.

Comment: obviously, if you wish to show the user such data, its not going to be a straight forward issue. have you looked into other options? tried something else?

Comment: still Looking for workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that it won't get loaded until or unless the whole image is loaded down the Client machine.

500MB is a huge file. Until it is loaded only `alt` attribute would be shown. You can try to lessen it down, and then send it to user.

I think what you can try would be to create a small image, and on some sort of events. Load other files, like Google Maps. They don't show you images that are zoomable, instead they show you layers of image and then depending on the zoom level on the map they change the source of the image file.

That way you can send images which are smaller in size. That would fastly load into the machine of the client, over slow speed internet (4MB like me) too. If it is heavy file. It won't load and you'll see only the `alt=""` attribute's value.

Comment: I have checked it with small size images with .tif format but the error is the same. But if I load .jpg it displays it.